# Doit-on dire merci quand quelqu'un nous présente ses condoléances ?

Tags: politesse

J'aimerais savoir s'il est correct de dire merci quand quelqu'un nous présente ses condoléances.

Comment: Je ne trouve pas cela choquant personnellement.

Comment: La formulation "doit-on" du titre est elle volontaire ? Car il y a une différence entre "doit-on" et "peut-on" ! :)

Comment: La formule doit-on est celle que j'ai souhaité utiliser. Cependant j'aurai pu poser la question, "Que dire quand ..."

Comment: You mean "J'aimerais"

Comment: @Benoît bientôt 2 ans que cette question a été posée. J'ai édité

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il est tout à fait correct de remercier quelqu'un qui vous présente ses condoléance, de même il est tout à fait correct de remercier par écrit (cela peut être une carte imprimée sur laquelle on ajoute quelques mots selon le destinataire) pour ceux qui n'ayant pu assister à l’enterrement ou à la crémation ont envoyé un mot de soutien.

Le deuil étant une situation personnelle et douloureuse, la spontanéité restera la réponse la plus adaptée, et, il n'y a pas de réel délai pour répondre par écrit.

Comment: On ne peut que répondre "Merci" à un simple "Mes condoléances" je pense... Par contre, suivant la proximité avec la personne, les gens ajoutent une phrase en accompagnement (par exemple, «c'était quelqu'un de bien» ou encore «il est parti trop tôt»...), qui permet de faire des réponses plus complètes et plus spontanées...

Answer (score 3):

Merci oui et c'est simple mais on peut encore dire : « merci pour votre considération. »

Answer (score 0):

Exact, d'accord avec vous tous, en cette occurrence, néanmoins cette interjection « merci » s'emploie trop souvent à tort et à travers comme mot passe-partout

1. le donneur de cadeau répondant aussi ainsi après avoir été remercié par le bénéficiaire au lieu de: « je vous en prie » ; « de rien » etc.
2. à la fin d'une « entrevue » à la télé, la personne questionnée, remerciée par le présentateur télé, répondant aussi par « merci » au lieu de : « de rien » ; « je vous en prie », « avec plaisir » etc.

Conclusion: On remercie pour un fait concret: un joli cadeau, une louange méritée, un réconfort nécessaire lors de fin de cérémonie funèbre. Mais, on ne remercie pas en retour.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse, et bienvenue sur le site :)